# How does LSTM network know when to forget?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

How does a LSTM network know when is a good time to forget the dependencies it has learned?

Comment: This question is offtopic for SO, because it is about machine learning theory, not specific programming problem. It is best to ask it at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: When the forget gate outputs a value close to 0.

Comment: the network has to learn the condition itself...